# get data under two different names when use union select

Tags: mysql, sql

```
"SELECT accepted AS accepted1 
 FROM friends WHERE from_id = :request_from AND to_id = :request_to 
 UNION SELECT accepted AS accepted2 
 FROM friends WHERE from_id = :request_to2 AND to_id = :request_from2"
```

in this query i am getting all results as accepted1 even if the second part (after UNION SELECT) of the query was true. 
How do i get the result as a accepted2 from second part of the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how the `UNION` statement behaves.  Very generally speaking, it combines the results of two queries into one.  So since you're only selecting a single field in each query, there is only a single column -- a single column can only have a single name.

If you need to know which query it came from, you could add a second column and use it to know.

```
SELECT accepted, 'accepted1' as source
FROM friends 
WHERE from_id = :request_from 
    AND to_id = :request_to 
UNION 
SELECT accepted, 'accepted2'  
FROM friends 
WHERE from_id = :request_to2 
    AND to_id = :request_from2
```

Comment: @sgeddes . . . You should use `union all` instead of `union` for this type of query.  The extra step of eliminating duplicates is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simplify the query by doing this:

```
SELECT accepted, from_id AS 'from' FROM friends 
WHERE (from_id = :request_from AND to_id = :request_to) 
   OR (from_id = :request_to2  AND to_id = :request_from2)
```

The second field `from` indicates which of the parts has been used